# List unpacking python with *

Tags: python-3.x, list, unpack

It's a very basic syntax and it should work:

```
# List Unpacking

numbers = [12, 23, 31, 46, 75, 85, 63, 50, 65, 63, 43, 1, 4, 56, 7, 4]
first, *others = numbers
print(first)
```

but I am getting this error, 
  File "app.py", line 4
    first, *others = numbers
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

have python removed this syntax or is there anything I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you certain you are running thos code in Python3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your python version, [additional unpacking generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) have been introduced since python 3.5

for example, I have python 3.7 and your code works well

Comment: my default was set for python 2 something.